# How do I get rid of two "viruses"?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, malware, antivirus

Yesterday I was looking at a sight and a message on my screen popped up on the incognito page;
An embedded page at s3.amazonaws.com says: MESSAGE! Congratulations Comcast Cable user, you have been chosen for a chance to get a enw iPhone 6s, MacBook Pro or iPad. Click OK to continue.

I can't get out of this pop up!!!

Then, this popped up:
www.launcer-apps.xyz says: 
Droid Turbo System Warning (2) Viruses Detected!

I ran the Verizon security check and it did not show any viruses.
If anyone knows how to remove these from the Android Turbo, please let me know.  Thank you

Comment: Not viruses: those do not exist in the Android ecosystem. Simply purge your browser's cache and avoid those websites. Also, you may want to install an ad-blocker (if you have root permissions).

Comment: In addition to the above comment by @death mask salesman, do check your installed apps for any malwares, which favors such ads, and uninstall them.

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry. These are **fake** virus scanners. They try to scare you by making you think your device is infected.

If you can't exit out of them simply close the browser tab you opened them in.

And if you rooted your phone you can download AdAway to remove the ads.